# Стилизация программы Vcl

Tags: delphi

Как можно натягивать на компоненты картинки тем самым стилизовать программу
Не предлагать Alpha скины итд мне нужно чтобы каждый компонент ScrollBar выглядил по разному а не одинаково.

Comment: Vcl - никак без кастомной отрисовки, а в ней - вы вольны рисовать как душе угодно.

Comment: В свежих версиях есть Стили и их скорее всего можно применять индивидуально, с некоторыми ухищрениями. Погуглите "delphi vcl styles"

Comment: @Kromster, можно и без ухищрений, можно создавать каждому компоненту свой стиль(каждому поименно), но это и есть кастомная отрисовка(точнее работает оно именно так), и динамически создать стиль будет достаточно проблематично(но возможно), проблематичней чем описать свой "обработчик" отрисовки...

Comment: И что мне делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из своего личного опыта могу посоветовать Вам использовать библиотеку компонентов [AlphaSkins](http://alphaskins.com). Для жителей СНГ - бесплатная версия без исходников и относительно быстрой тех.поддержкой. За небольшую сумму можно получить версию с исходниками. Ни в коем случае не реклама и я сам не являюсь их разработчиком; лично использую для мелких поделок бесплатную версию. Баги встречаются, как у всех, но не всегда они "смертельные", да и на форуме можно получить помощь от тамошних завсегдатаев.

Ниже на картинке пример того, что Вы (если я правильно Вас понял) хотите получить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это скриншот формы, находящейся в `design-time`. Как видно, присутствуют два компонента `TsSkinManager`, которые подключены к компонентам `TsMemo`, `TsScrollBar`. Применяются два *разных* скин-файла. Требуемый эффект достигнут буквально несколькими кликами мыши.
Четыре компонента справа - это самостоятельные полосы прокрутки (имеющие `Handle`).

Советую попробовать. Реализовывать подобное самому с нуля - гарантированная трата времени.

Comment: Да пожалуй это то что нужно

Comment: @AimonZ. если мой ответ помог Вам, то примите его в качестве окончательного.